# How to take the mean of a column each k elements (hours)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of (286101, 4), It is a dataset of the contaminants of a city,  notice that there are several stations:

```
       date     hour   station   CO   
0     1/1/13     1        CA      1    
1     1/1/13     2        CA      5    
2     1/1/13     3        CA      4    
3     1/1/13     1        NY      3    
4     1/1/13     2        NY      6    
5     1/1/13     3        NY      2
```

I want to take the mean of CO for each 24 hours for each station, and keep the measurement of the hour, I have tried a simple groupby but I'am getting the mean of the day (as it's supposed to be).

For the sake of the example, let's say that I am supposed to take the mean each 2 hours, then the expected output would be:

```
       date     hour   station   CO   CO_mean
0     1/1/13     1        CA      1     na
1     1/1/13     2        CA      5    3.0
2     1/1/13     3        CA      4    4.5
3     1/1/13     1        NY      3     na
4     1/1/13     2        NY      6    4.5
5     1/1/13     3        NY      2    4.0
```

In the first date of each station I would expect an nan because there is no a previous element. In the case of the mean of each 24 hours, the first 24 hours would be nans.

Is there a way to do this without using a for-if loop? I think that it would take hours to complete.

I hope have described the problem in a clear manner, pardon me if there are grammar mistakes, it's no my mother language...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try: `df.groupby(['date','hour','station']).CO.rolling(2).mean()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For timeseries data, I think it is good practice to work on date/datetime objects, rather than their scalar values. Here's what I'll do (based on your 2-hour rolling mean example)

```
import pandas as pd

>>>df
       date     hour   station   CO   
0     1/1/13     1        CA      1    
1     1/1/13     2        CA      5    
2     1/1/13     3        CA      4    
3     1/1/13     1        NY      3    
4     1/1/13     2        NY      6    
5     1/1/13     3        NY      2  

# Create a datetime column
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime([''.join([' '.join([df.loc[i, 'date'], str(df.loc[i, 'hour'])]),':00']) for i in df.index])
# We can now drop the scalar date and hour columns
df.drop(['date', 'hour'], axis=1, inplace=True)
# Sort into proper order so that rolling() is computed correctly
df.sort_values(['station','datetime'], inplace=True)
# Set the datetime column as the dataframe index
df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)

>>>df.groupby('station').rolling(2).mean()
                              CO
station datetime
CA      2013-01-01 01:00:00  NaN
        2013-01-01 02:00:00  3.0
        2013-01-01 03:00:00  4.5
NY      2013-01-01 01:00:00  NaN
        2013-01-01 02:00:00  4.5
        2013-01-01 03:00:00  4.0
```

**Edit** Includes a sorting step to make sure that `rolling()` is computed correctly - in case the datetime order is not sorted properly in the first place.